# Matplotlib - Diverging Contourplot - How make Center more concise

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I'm trying to make a good visualization of a contour-plot for the scalar field [image].

```py
# Get Figure and Ax to plot on
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1 , 1, figsize=(16,9))

# Plot Contour Lines
CS = ax.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=levels_check_all)

# Recast levels to new class for Fomratting
CS.levels = [nf(val) for val in CS.levels]
# Plot Labels into Plot with __repr__
ax.clabel(CS, CS.levels, inline=True, fmt='%r', fontsize=10)

# Plot the given Point in red
ax.plot(point_x, point_y, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

The contourplot generated by this code looks like this. (I know it's cluttered)

[image]

I now tried altering code, so that it is clear through color-coding, that this scalar field has an exponential growth.

```py
# Get Figure and Ax to plot on
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1 , 1, figsize=(16,9))

# Plot Contour Lines
CS = ax.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=levels_check_all, cmap=cm.coolwarm, norm=mcolors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.03))

# Recast levels to new class for Fomratting
CS.levels = [nf(val) for val in CS.levels]
# Plot Labels into Plot with __repr__
ax.clabel(CS, CS.levels, inline=True, fmt='%r', fontsize=10)

# Plot the given Point in red
ax.plot(point_x, point_y, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

The resulting Graph looks like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to make the values around 0 a bit more concise, so that they are better readable. Is it somehow possible to 'shift' the colors a bit towards to center?

If not I might just plot the clabels in black, but I'd rather have them in the same color as the contourline.

Comment: Try creating your own customized colormap using `vmax=8.0` `cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("mycmap", [(0.5/vmax,"red"),(4/vmax,"white"),(8/vmax, "blue")])`  Manipulate the (value,color) pairs however & how many you want.